# How to get count of unique values in a column group by the primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, count

I am new to sql and i have this problem in hand.
I have a table temp which has id and flag as its columns.

```
ID FLAG               
-- ---- 
A    1                      
A    1                      
A    0                      
B    1                      
B    0                      
B    0                      
C    0                      
C    0                      
C    0
```

I need the 1's and 0's count with respect to each ID.

The desired output is

```
ID    OnesCount    ZerosCount
---   ---------    ----------
A       2            1
B       1            2
C       0            3
```

I tried a lot i can get them individually by

```
select id,count(*) ZerosCount from temp where flag = 0 group by id

select id,count(*) OnesCount from temp where flag = 1 group by id
```

But do not understand how to join and get the desired output.
Can some one please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific case you can do like this:

```
select customer_id ID, 
       sum(pwr_flag) OnesCount, 
       sum(1-pwr_flag) ZerosCount 
  from temp_pwr 
 group by customer_id
```

In a more generic case you can use `case when`:

```
select customer_id ID, 
       sum(case pwr_flag when 1 then 1 else 0 end) OnesCount, 
       sum(case pwr_flag when 0 then 1 else 0 end) ZerosCount 
       sum(case pwr_flag when 17 then 1 else 0 end) SeventeensCount 
  from temp_pwr 
 group by customer_id
```

Comment: The first statement gives the below output

`ID         ONESCOUNT              ZEROSCOUNT             

---------- ---------------------- ---------------------- 

A          0                      1                      

B          0                      2                      

C          0                      3`

all 0s as ouput for one's count where as the zero count is correct.

Comment: The same with the second statement also.All counts as 0 for onescount and correct count for zeros count

Comment: Second one after edit, 
`select customer_id ID, 
       sum(case pwr_flag when 1 then 1 else 0 end) OnesCount, 
       sum(case pwr_flag when 0 then 1 else 0 end) ZerosCount 
 from temp_pwr 
 group by customer_id`
this works! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select customer_id, 
   count(case when pwr_flag = 0 then 1 end) ZerosCount,
   count(case when pwr_flag = 1 then 1 end) OnessCount 
from temp_pwr
group by customer_id
```